# Javascript referencing values inside the object it self

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, this

I have a config file for my Node.js application which looks like this:

```
// Development specific configuration
// ==================================
module.exports = {

....

  ip: "localhost",
  //Rabbit MQ
  rabbitmq: {
    username: 'foo',
    password: 'bar',
    ip: 'amqp://'+this.username+':'+this.password+'@rabbitmq',
    queues: {
      name: 'foo'
    }
  }, 
....

};
```

Here is what the module looks like where I use this config file:

```
var config = require ('../../config/environment');
this.con = amqp.connect (config.rabbitmq.ip);
```

I am getting undefined for the username and password:

```
amqp://undefined:undefined@rabbitmq
```

I have tried multiple ways such as:

1. Creating getter functions inside the object like this:

   ```
   rabbitmq: {
   username: 'foo',
   password: 'bar',
   getUsername: function (){
      return this.username;
   },
   getpassword: function (){
      return this.password;
   },
   ip: 'amqp://'+this.getUsername()+':'+this.getpassword()+'@rabbitmq',
   ```
2. Created a self value and assign 'this' and reference it:

   ```
   self: this,
   ...
   ip: 'amqp://'+self.rabbitmq.username+':'+self.rabbitmq.password+'@rabbitmq',
   ```

   ..

I cannot get the scope to properly work. Am I missing something basic? How can I make this happen? 
Please help.

Comment: Can you try this ip: 'amqp://'+username+':'+password+'@rabbitmq',

Comment: ip: 'amqp://'+username+':'+password+'@rabbitmq',
                  ^

ReferenceError: username is not defined

Comment: Being a part of an expression - `this` holds the value of the current scope you're running at. So what you want to do is not possible (and is not necessary to be honest).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var config = {
    ip : "localhost", //Rabbit MQ
    rabbitmq : {
        username : 'foo',
        password : 'bar',
        queues : {
            name : 'foo'
        }
    }
};
```

`config` is now declared in module scope so you can reuse its values

```
config.rabbitmq.ip = 'amqp://' + config.rabbitmq.username + ':' + config.rabbitmq.password + '@rabbitmq';
module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
var username = 'foo';
var password = 'bar';

module.exports = {
  ip: "localhost",
  //Rabbit MQ
  rabbitmq: {
    username: username,
    password: password,
    ip: 'amqp://'+username+':'+password+'@rabbitmq',
    queues: {
      name: 'foo'
    }
  }
};
```